# Sorbet: check for a class that includes a target module

Tags: sorbet

Sorbet's `T.class_of` can be used to match descendant classes, but not classes that include a module:

```rb
module X; end
class A; end
class B < A; include X; end

B.ancestors # => [B, X, A, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel, BasicObject]

sig { params(x: T.class_of(A)).void }
def is_a(x); end

is_a(A)  # => ok
is_a(B)  # => ok

sig { params(x: T.class_of(X)).void }
def is_b(x); end

is_b(X)  # => ok
is_b(B)  # => error
```

According to https://sorbet.org/docs/class-of, this is because B is not an
instance of X's singleton_class:

```rb
B.is_a?(A.singleton_class)  # => true
B.is_a?(B.singleton_class)  # => true
B.is_a?(X.singleton_class)  # => false
```

But no alternative suggestion is provided. Is there a way to type check based on the contents of a class' ancestors? i.e. something like `class_of` that can be used to check for a class mixing in a module?

Comment: There's no existing solution IIUC but this is filed as https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/issues/62